# Xcode version 11.4.1 is not recognizing boost/hana.hpp but i is on my system

Tags: boost

i am using clang version 11.0.3 , and from a terminal window i can build my program which has a boost/hana.hpp via this command:
g++  -std=c++17 main.cpp, this compiles just fine.

When trying to use xcode to build my code, i get boost/hana.hpp  file not found.

how do i get xcode to recognize this library.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had to add "/usr/local/include" to my build path under the build settings.  this is the location on my mac where the boost libraries were installed.